# How do I offset my auto scroll?

Tags: jquery, scroll, autoscroll

I need to offset my auto scroll function by about 50-100px whenever it transistions from one div to another.

The script below is what I'm using. When I click a link it smoothly scrolls me down to the top of the associated Div.

However I have a sticky header at the top of my site so this always covers the div you transition to.

Is there anyway I can set the transition to go to the top of the div but then offset it by -100px?

My code is below.

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();

    var target = this.hash;
    var $target = $(target);

    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
    }, 900, 'swing', function () {
        window.location.hash = target;
    });
});
 });
```

Comment: You're probably referring to setting `z-index:-100px` ?

Comment: Not quite.
What I mean is when i click a link and the page scrolls to the top of the selected div, it shouldn't scroll to the top of the div exactly but instead 100px above.

Reason being is that i have a sticky header with a height of 100px. This sticky header should always be on show so changing the Z-index isn't what I'm after.

I'd rather the auto scroll stopped 100px above each div so the header doesn't cover it when you scroll to it.

Comment: Check answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so from your comment here's what you can try:

```
$('html, body').stop().animate({
        'scrollTop': ($target.offset().top - 100) // 100 is hard coded though you can make it dynamic if you know identifier of your sticky div like so: ($target.offset().top - $("#sticky-div").outerHeight())
    }, 900, 'swing', function () {
        window.location.hash = target;
});
```

Comment: Perfect thankyou! I didn't realise it was that simple.